# QWebEngineView modify web content before render

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit, qtwebengine, qwebpage

I have three questions about QWebengineView (Qt 5.7.0):

1. How can I modify the web content (add extra html/javascript) during load (before render)
2. How can I get events when javascript resource included in webpage is loading ( I want to modify them, too).
3. I get html content by page()->toHtml then set it back by setHtml , but content rendered don't like original (seems to loss format)

Thanks for help!

Comment: To be honest best answer to all three questions - use QtWebKit

Comment: @evilruff Depending on the Qt version he is using, Qt WebKit is deprecated (if the version > Qt5.5). So no, not the best answer

Comment: Question was about qwebengineview.. qtwebkit is completely different story